# Do I need rel="nofollow" in external scripts and stylesheets?

Tags: javascript, css, html, seo

I already read a lot about SEO and web performance, but now I have a dumb question that I'm trying to answer myself, but I can't. Is good use `rel="nofollow"` in many cases for improve SEO, it's well knowed and documented.

### But now a thing to think:

If I have external stylesheets (.css) and scripts (.js) that doesn't is hosted in my website, do I need use `rel="nofollow"` to improve SEO?

---

### Example:

Supose that my website is [Google](http://www.google.com). If I have the following content inside my page:

```
<link href="http://www.blabla.com/myAwesomeStylesheet.css" type="text/css">
<script href="http://www.chucknorris.com/youWillDie.min.js" type="text/javascript">
```

Which one is better:

```
<!-- First way -->
<link href="http://www.blabla.com/myAwesomeStylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script href="http://www.chucknorris.com/youWillDie.min.js" type="text/javascript">

<!-- Second way -->
<link href="http://www.blabla.com/myAwesomeStylesheet.css" rel="nofollow" type="text/css">
<script href="http://www.chucknorris.com/youWillDie.min.js" rel="nofollow" type="text/javascript">    

<!-- Third way -->
<link href="http://www.blabla.com/myAwesomeStylesheet.css" type="text/css">
<script href="http://www.chucknorris.com/youWillDie.min.js" type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: No you don't need to have nofollow, it won't have an effect on SEO. Nofollow should only be used on anchors in your site that you don't want indexed.

Comment: @JohnConde, why this is off-topic? If exist "SEO" tag in StackOverflow, why I can't post questions with this tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SEO advice is off-topic on Stack Overflow. But your question can still be answered here, because …

In HTML5, **the [`nofollow` link type](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/links.html#link-type-nofollow) may only be used with `a` and `area` elements.**

So don’t use it on `link` elements.

For [`script` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/scripting-1.html#the-script-element), there is **no `rel` attribute** in the first place.

(Note: Your `script` element has the `type` value `text/css`. It’s likely that this is not what you want. If it’s JavaScript, use `text/javascript` ([or omit the `type` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/scripting-1.html#attr-script-type)).)

Comment: Thanks, perfect answer. And I don't understand why SEO is off-topic :/

Answer (score 3):

Well you have "text/css" in a script tag in all three, so I'd remove them for a start! :)

Adding `rel=nofollow` to your stylesheet and script tags though will have no SEO benefit.

**[Interesting read](http://blog.woorank.com/2013/05/the-flow-of-link-juice/).**

Comment: He actually has `text/css` as the `type` for all four examples.

Comment: @Travis - True - my browser didn't add a horizontal scroll bar to the code box, so I didn't see the first two properly :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unor give me a better answer. Anyway, thanks for alert me about wrong code :P