# can use rel attribute with nofollow value inside internal script tag for ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, nofollow

Can i use `rel="nofollow"` value inside internal script tag ?
like this:
Some ajax request following by google crawls .

```
<script rel="nofollow">
// some ajax request here
</script>
```

please tell me if this way is a good idea for tell google do not follow ajax request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I need rel="nofollow" in external scripts and stylesheets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21196528/do-i-need-rel-nofollow-in-external-scripts-and-stylesheets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work with `script` element. Instead, you can specify the url that you call with ajax in your `robots.txt`. (Or use robots meta tag to disallow crawling all site)

Take a look at : https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt

Comment: I can't use bobots.txt beacuse begining url are dynamic and always change and i can't robots wildcards

Comment: @farzad why can't you use wildcards?

Comment: because my url is like this : /en-us/shop-52158/city-la/home/product/ begining url is dynamic @Adam Wolski

Comment: what is the problem with /*/home/product for instance?

Comment: yes you can. Take a look at: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use `nofollow` there as it only applies to `a` and `area` elements:

> The `nofollow` keyword may be used with `a` and `area` elements. This keyword does not create a hyperlink, but annotates any other hyperlinks created by the element (the implied hyperlink, if no other keywords create one).

https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/links.html#link-type-nofollow

If you want to block spiders from accessing certain URLs of your site, use a `robots.txt` file.